# Use custom Mongo db with Powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions, mongodb

I have a custom  mongo database, that database contains information about pages.I need to query it in order to use SEP to create pages according to that info, ig, adding renderings component, etc. That mongo collection has info required to see what component rendering I should use, also it has the data of the page to be created.  So I have to query that mongodb from Powershell, the according to that data create an item.  Can I 'atached' that mongo database to sitecore, and from SEP query the mongodb? I dont seem to find any documentation on how to do so, using mongodb.

Comment: This is a pretty low-quality and very broad question. Can you elaborate more on it? What are you trying to achieve, what have you tried, what issues are you seeing, etc?

Comment: I think there is a bit of a language barrier in play here. But if I am reading you correctly; this is what you want to do:  You have a collection of documents sitting in MongoDB. And you want to create a SPE script to read through these documents, and create Sitecore items. Is that correct?